# Summer Blockbuster season is coming, would you like to write a review for the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I'd like to get people to write reviews for some of the major movies coming out this year. Here is a [quick schedule](http://www.movieinsider.com/movies/-/2013/) for 2013:

- G.I. Joe: Retaliation - March 28th
- Jurassic Park 3D - April 5th
- The Evil Dead - April 5th
- [Star Trek: The Best of Both Worlds](http://www.fathomevents.com/#!star-trek-best-of-both-worlds/more-info/details) - April 25th
- Ironman 3 - May 3rd
- Star Trek Into Darkness - May 17th
- After Earth - May 31st
- Man of Steel - June 14th
- World War Z - June 21st
- The Wolverine - July 26th
- Ender's Game - November 1st
- Thor: The Dark Worlds - November 8th
- The Hunger Games: Catching Fire - November 22nd
- The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug - December 13th

This is an not a complete list. If you have another movie not on this list and it is on topic you'd be welcome to write a review about it.

None of us are film critics (that I'm aware of), so a more conversation tone about the film is okay. Examples of things to talk about:

- How does the movie compare to the written work / previous installments?
- Changes from the source material are inevitable, what are the most notable differences?
- What changes improved the storytelling, what changes seemed to detract from the storytelling?

If you'd like to contribute post an answer with the movie you'd like to commit to seeing and writing a review for. Ideally that review would be ready within a couple of weeks of the film's release.

Comment: Since we now attract our share of visit, it would be an idea to check if we can get some of us invited to the advance press screening of some of those. This way, the review could be ready for the film's official release.

Comment: I'll be happy to a write up as I will watch all of these but I can't commit for sure to any one of them in a timely fashion.

Comment: WWZ starts a week later over here ... Yaaaaaaaaaay!

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sublist of the films I intend to see, witht he UK release dates

- Ironman 3 - *26th April*
- Star Trek Into Darkness - *10th May*
- The Wolverine - 26th July
- Thor: The Dark Worlds - *30th October*
- The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug - 13th December

Whilst I can't commit to writing all of them, I'm happy to commit to one or two once more people answer, and I can fill in the gaps hopefully.

Comment: Would you still be interesting in writing something for the site for Thor: The Dark Worlds?

Answer (score 1):

I have an interest in covering Ender's Game if nobody else will take it (and at least some [on-topic qualifications](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/enders-game/topusers) :)

However, I can't commit to November post since I don't plan to see it till DVDs come out couple months later (unless DavRob's idea from the above comment works).

**UPDATE**: Seems @Beofett will take the on-time review for this movie.

Comment: I get to see very few movies in the theater, ever since my son was born, but this is one I'm going to see if my wife would be willing to see as a Date Night.  If so, and if you don't mind, I may step in and offer to cover it before the DVDs are released.

Comment: @Beofett - looking forward to your review! Your writing beats mine :)

Comment: Thanks!  I still need permission from my wife, though, as well as a willing babysitter...  ;)  I'm fairly sure I'll be able to do it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Having checked with my wife, I can commit to both *Enders Game* and *Iron Man 3* (my wife's a Robert Downey Jr. fan).

Comment: Were you able to see Iron Man 3? Are you still willing to write a review of it?

Comment: We have not seen it yet, but I hope to in the next week or two (we need to arrange a baby-sitter).  If it looks like it will take longer than that, I'll let you know.  Otherwise, I'll have a review within 24 hours of seeing it.

Comment: Would you still be interesting in writing something for the site for Ender's Game?

Comment: @JackBNimble Yep, still planning on going to see it (hopefully not long after it comes out... I'll start looking for a babysitter now!).

Answer (score 1):

I'm wanting to see almost all of them, but it might take me a while... Jurrasic Park, Star Trek, Irom Man, Ender's Game, the Hobbit, Hunger Games, and probably a few others I'll be watching at some point in time... I would be able to see more if Stack Exchange can work some magic;-)

Comment: Did you happen to see Jurassic Park in 3D? If so I'd love a review of it.

Comment: @JackBNimble: Long story, but the short is, no, and I'm not likely to...

Comment: Would you still be interested in writing something for the blog for one of the 3 movies you listed still coming out this fall (such as Ender's Game, The Hunger Games, or The Hobbit) ?

Comment: @JackBNimble: If I end up seeing them. Certainly if SE will pay for my tickets;-)